# How to find Which Module Giving this error : Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, requirejs

Every UI Grid generating this Error.

This Error Only giving in Live Not in local instance, as well as Other Server. All the Instance same Code Same DB.

How to find Which Module Giving this error?

[image]

Comment: You can check by disable 3rd party module

Answer (score 0):

this is due to a typing issue in your js file use you might have used `require()` in place of `define()`

so this the correct way to use js component

```
define([
  'uiComponent'
], function(
  uiComponent
) {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Return the UI Component
   */
  return uiComponent.extend({
    /**
     * Initialization method
     */
    initialize: function () {
      this._super();
    }
  });
});
```

hope this helps thanks!

Comment: I know this Solution But how can I find which JS giving error.

Comment: that could be an issue with the recent module that might have added if you are not able to catch in console